# Quick Approach: List the Files description have been changed in the last 3 Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, bash

I have a SQL Server Express that is Accessed by Mutli users Remotely.

And All the times they are changes that happens on the Databases. I only would like to who changed, what time, and if possible what was changed into the database.

What will be the best SQL script that can find the files that wer changed for during the last 3 days?

I Have found this [LINK](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/can-i-see-historical-queries-run-on-a-sql-server-database) but was not same result

```
SELECT  dest.text
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE   deqs.last_execution_time > '5/19/2011 11:00'
        AND dest.text LIKE 'WITH%';
```

Comment: Depending of your SQLServer version, you can use `Temporal table` on each table you want to track changes. To know who modified a record, you may add a column `username` and a trigger.

Comment: @Kobi thank for your reply. I have a Database called CLONE. Ther I have ModifiedUsername in each Table. Since I would like to read from all the tables in the Database, That's what I am Asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATEADD(d, -3, GETDATE())

```
SELECT  dest.text
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE   deqs.last_execution_time > CAST(DATEADD(d, -3, GETDATE()) AS date)
        AND dest.text LIKE 'WITH%';
```

Comment: @giorg02, Briliant approach, But it's return a blank TEXT, and another database return " - The user does not have permission to perform this action.
-Permission , How to Fix that?

Comment: Thank you very much Giorgi02, Your approach leads to a great result. I surely needed to change the date limit. Thanks again

Comment: it's nice if I helped you